# How to make counter stop before variable timelimit and so it doesnt exceed it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm currently doing a task where a user enters an amount of time (e.g 5 mins) and it generates a 'playlist'. It creates a 2D array, with the name, artist, genre and time length. This is my code so far:

```
import random
import csv

playlist = []

timelimit = int(input("How long would you like the playlist to be: \n>> "))
data = list(csv.reader(open("song.csv")))
counter = 0

while True:
    random_song = random.choice(data)
    playlist.append(random_song)
    index = playlist.index(random_song)
    num = int(playlist[index][3])
    counter += num
    if counter >= timelimit:
        break

print(playlist)
```

"The user inputs a time limit(e.g. 10 minutes) and it generates a playlist that does not last longer than this time", is what i'm supposed to do. How am I supposed to make it not last longer than this time without it adding only one song?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem with your code ?

Comment: @LoïcG. This is a code logic question, currently it loops until the condition is met, OP simply wants to avoid that last iteration.

Comment: The problem is, well here's an example. A user enters the number '10'. I want it so it adds songs until it either reaches the number 10 or if the next song is too big and therefore can't be added again.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    random_song = random.choice(data)
    index = data.index(random_song)     
    num = int(data[index][3])
    counter += num
    if counter >= timelimit:
        break
    playlist.append(random_song)
```

By moving the .append to after your break condition it will not append a song that breaks the condition. The only thing im not 100% sure about is the format of your data (note that I am now getting index and num from the data and not playlist), so num may not compute. If this fails try your own ways of generating num without needing to first append the song.

Comment: How you handle the case where the second random selected song will fails the condition ? OP said `without it adding only one song`. That why I asked what is the problem with its code ;)

Comment: @LoïcG. I interpreted that as OP not wanting a single song to be added no matter the length input. If a single song best fits the time, then my answer would return a single song, but I am guessing that is actually what OP wanted

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, just gives me an error, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I added a seperate counter where the number gets subtracted and removes the random song from the list. Here's the code, I added, the variable newtime and everything else was based around that.

```
import random
import csv

playlist = []

timelimit = int(input("How long would you like the playlist to be: \n>> "))
data = list(csv.reader(open("song.csv")))
counter = 0
newtime = timelimit

while True:
    random_song = random.choice(data)
    playlist.append(random_song)
    index = playlist.index(random_song)
    num = int(playlist[index][3])
    newtime -= num
    if newtime < 0:
        playlist.remove(random_song)
    counter += num
    if counter >= timelimit:
        break

print(playlist)
```